# Pass variadic template argument as reference to std::thread via perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Consider this simple variadic template function that spawns a thread and forwards the args to the thread function.
Why do I get a template substitution failure on the thread constructor here?

```
std::thread t;

void test3(int& a)
{
    a = 10;
}

template<class ...Args>
void test(Args&&... args)
{
   t = std::thread(test3, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto timer = 2s;

    int a = 1;
    test(a);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timer);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    t.join();
}
```

Compiler output:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/invoke.h: In substitution of 
'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> constexpr typename 
std::__invoke_result<_Functor, _ArgTypes>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, 
_Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(int&); _Args = {int}]':
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/thread:233:29:   required by 
substitution of 'template<long unsigned int ..._Ind> decltype 
(std::__invoke(_S_declval<_Ind>()...)) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void 
(*)(int&), int> >::_M_invoke<_Ind ...>(std::_Index_tuple<_Ind1 ...>) [with 
long unsigned int ..._Ind = {0, 1}]'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/thread:240:2:   required from 
'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int&), int> >'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/thread:127:22:   required from 
'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)
 (int&); _Args = {int&}]'
prog.cc:23:14:   required from 'void test(Args&& ...) [with Args = {int&}]'
prog.cc:43:11:   required from here
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/invoke.h:89:5: error: no type 
named 'type' in 'struct std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int&), int>'
```

When I wrap the forwarding of the arguments with a std::ref like this:

```
std::thread(test3, std::ref(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

It works. Aren't the arguments supposed to be perfectly forwarded in the first place?

Comment: [`thread`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) is defined in terms of decay_copy.

Comment: To elaborate on what ildjarn is hinting at, the function you pass is called with a copy of the referenced integer. And that copy is an expiring value. It cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: @StoryTeller is the only solution then to use std::ref on the args?

Comment: I suggest letting the caller decide, i.e. `test(std::ref(a));`

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks. I also noticed that if I were to call the templated function with a reference type like so: 
    test<int&>(std::ref(a)); 
I get the same error. What if my function was more complex and I needed to explicitly specify the type in the angle brackets?

Comment: Well, add a layer of indirection. For instance `std::forward` accepts the deduced type and a reference. That's how the magic of the forwarding works. But you can write your own function that accepts the deduced/specified type and a reference. Then it can decide to return a `std::reference_wrapper` or just `std::forward` the original reference. Also, note that in your case by specifying `int&` the `std::ref` was pretty much ignored. That's because the wrapper is implicitly convertible both from and to a reference.

Answer (score 1):

By default thread *copies* its arguments.  The alternative is madness, as references to local data tend to be unlikely to last the entire thread's lifetime.

If you want, if you really really want, to pass a reference wrap it with `std::ref`:

```
test(std::ref(a));
```

now, your code still exhibits undefined behaviour; `sleep` does not synchronize access and all unsynchronized reading/writing is simply undefined behaviour.

For a concrete "non-hostile" example, compilers are free to assume `a` remains unchanged in `main` until after `join` as that is the first synchronization action you engage in, so all non-local effects can be ignored, and it is not modified locally.

They may fail to detect this optimization, and your undefined behaviour may result in what you want to happen happening, but nasal demons can do *anything*.

So move the print after `join`.

---

This is C++.  Variable lifetime management is the job of the programmer.  References dangling between threads implicitly is a really bad idea.